# p:commandButton ajax + BlockUI/GraphicImage spinner - timing out after a minute

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

PrimeFaces 6.1, WildFly 8.1.0, OmniFaces version 2.7

I'm working on an application that basically allows folks at my company to submit requests for training certifications for employees and submit them into a back-end table for further processing. I've got a form structured like this:

```
<h:form id="classRequestForm">       
                    <p:panel header="Select Certification" style="width: 475px;  margin: 4px;">
 
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                            <h:panelGroup>       
                                        <h:panelGrid> 
                                            <h:outputLabel value="Certification Title(s) (Limit: 5)" />                                 
                                            <p:autoComplete id="autoCertSearch" value="#{trainingAlterView.certRequestList}" queryDelay="100" maxResults="30"
                                                styleClass="courseMultiAutoComplete" completeMethod="#{certificationListAutoComplete.getByKeywords2}"
                                                var="certSelect"  panelStyle="width: 500px !important;"
                                                converter="#{certConverter}" requiredMessage="Cert Required" itemValue="#{certSelect}"
                                                emptyMessage="No Matches!" itemLabel="#{certSelect.certTitle}"
                                                title="Start typing Cert Title" selectLimit="5" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3"
                                                scrollHeight="300" multiple="true">

                                                <p:column headerText="Title" style="width: 500px">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{certSelect.certTitle}" />
                                                </p:column>
                                                <p:column headerText="Type">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{certSelect.certFamily}" />
                                                </p:column>  
                                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.certListRefresh}" />  
                                        <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.certListRefresh}" /> 
                                        <p:ajax event="valueChange" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.certListRefresh}" /> 
                                        <p:ajax event="change" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.certListRefresh}" />   
                                    </p:autoComplete>
                                        
                                            <p:watermark for="autoCertSearch" value="Start typing Cert Title"
                                                onclick="PrimeFaces.cleanWatermarks();" oncomplete="PrimeFaces.showWatermarks();" />
        
                                        </h:panelGrid>                           
                                        <p style="margin:0;padding:0;text-align:right;"> 

                                            <p:commandLink
                                                action="#{trainingAlterView.certListRefresh}" update="tarSelectForm" process="@this" partialSubmit="true"
                                                style="color:#00f;text-decoration:underline; text-align:right;margin-top: 10px;" value="View Training Assignment Summary..." oncomplete="PF('errorArea2').show();"> 

                                            </p:commandLink> 
                                        </p>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            
                             
                            

                        </p:panelGrid>

                    </p:panel> 

                    <p:panel header="Add Employee(s)" style="width: 475px;  margin: 4px;">

                    
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:panelGrid>
                                    <h:outputLabel value="Employee" />
                                    <p:autoComplete size="55" id="employeeToSearch" value="#{trainingAlterView.personList}" queryDelay="100" maxResults="30"
                                        styleClass="empMultiAutoComplete" converter="#{personConverter}" required="true"
                                        requiredMessage="Employee Required" panelStyle="width: 500px !important;"
                                        completeMethod="#{personListAutoComplete.getByKeywords2}" var="person" itemValue="#{person}"
                                        emptyMessage="No Matches!" itemLabel="#{person.fullName} (Badge: #{person.personId}, Shift: #{person.shift}, Dept: #{person.dept})" forceSelection="true" minQueryLength="3"
                                        scrollHeight="300" multiple="true" 
                                        placeholder="Start typing Emp Name">

                                         
                                        <p:column headerText="Id" style="width: 5px;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.personId}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Name" style="width: 100px;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.fullName}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Shift" style="width: 5px;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.shift}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Dept/Div" style="width: 10px;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.dept}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column  headerText="MSS Supervisor Badge" style="width: 100px">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.supervisorId}" />
                                        </p:column> 
                                        <p:column  headerText="ATA Supervisor Badge" style="width: 100px">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{person.ataSupervisorId}" />
                                        </p:column>  

                                        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.persListRefresh}" />  
                                        <p:ajax event="itemUnselect" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.persListRefresh}" /> 
                                        <p:ajax event="valueChange" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.persListRefresh}" /> 
                                        <p:ajax event="change" delay="100" listener="#{trainingAlterView.persListRefresh}" />    
                                
                                    </p:autoComplete>
                                                                          
                                    
                                </h:panelGrid>
        
                    
                            </h:panelGroup>
                            
                            <p:commandButton style="margin-top: 10px;" value="All Personnel" onclick="PF('rosterQuickAddDialog').show(); return false" /> 

                        </p:panelGrid>
                    
                    </p:panel>
    
                    <p:panel header="Justification" style="width: 475px;  margin: 4px;">
                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
                            <p:outputLabel for="justification" value="Category:" />
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{trainingAlterView.justification}" id="justification" style="width:275px" required="true" requiredMessage="Justification Required">       
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Apprentice Program" itemValue="Apprentice Program" />
                                
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Attrition - Employee retiring" itemValue="Attrition - Employee retiring" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Attrition - Employee changing shift within the same department" itemValue="Attrition - Employee changing shift within the same department" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Attrition - Employee changing department" itemValue="Attrition - Employee changing department" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Attrition - Employee changing supervisor within the same department on the same shift" itemValue="Attrition - Employee changing supervisor within the same department on the same shift" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:panelGrid>

                        <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                            <p:outputLabel for="comments" value="Detailed Summary:" />
                            
                              <p:inputTextarea requiredMessage="Summary Required" value="#{trainingAlterView.comments}" placeholder="E.g., An employee retired and we need to train a new employee to perform a similar task." style="width:310px" id="comments" rows="5" cols="30" required="true" maxlength="4000"  autoResize="false" />
                        </p:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>

            <p:commandButton id="submit" update=":classRequestForm:employeeToSearch :classRequestForm:justification :classRequestForm:comments" style="margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;" ajax="true" value="Request Certification(s)" action="#{trainingAlterView.addCertRequest2}" />   
                      
            <p:button style="margin-top: 3px; margin-right: 10px;" value="Reset" ajax="false" type="reset" />        
                     
                         
                        <p:blockUI block="classRequestForm" trigger="submit">
                            <p:graphicImage name="gfx/ajax-loader.gif" />
                        </p:blockUI>
</h:form>
```

Which triggers a function that looks like this when the "submit" commandButton is clicked (omitted a lot of the code but here's the basic idea):

```
public void addCertRequest2() {  
        
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
 

        Boolean hasDeptAdmin  = null;
        Boolean hasDeptMgr    = null;
        Boolean hasSupervisor = null; 
        Boolean isContractor = false;
        String providerString = null;  
        String ccs = null;
        Integer managerLevel           = null;
        Boolean mgr_check              = false;
        Integer supervisor_mgr_level   = null;
        List<LearningObject> subCertDetail = null;
        List<LearningObject> assignedItems = null;
        List<String> assignedItemsCertIds = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> certRequestListIds = new ArrayList<String>(); 
        List<TrainingAlterRequest> pendingRequests = null;
        List<String> rosterBadgeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Set<String> dupResultArr = null; 

        for(int j = 0; j < personList.size(); j++) {
            rosterBadgeList.add(0, personList.get(j).getPersonId()); 
        }  
        

        for(int c=0; c < certRequestList.size(); c++) {
            certRequestListIds.add(0, certRequestList.get(c).getCertId());  
        } 

        for(int certLoop=0; certLoop<certRequestList.size(); certLoop++) { 
            [...]
                         for(int k=0; k<personList.size(); k++)
                                
                             // nested loop that does additional processing/duplicate checks/etc.
                         }
            switch(...) {
                [...]
            }
        }

        
        [Hibernate/DB calls...] 
        [Hide form]
        [Messages.addAjaxMessage success messages]
    return;
     }
```

The function does exactly what I want it to do and works perfectly - when, say, one or two certifications are requested for or 5 so of employees (for a total of 5-10 certifications requested).

However, if I attempt to request 5 certifications (currently the max on the form) for 5-10 employees (25-50 requests initiated), it can take several minutes (3-5 mins). After about exactly a minute (60 seconds) the BlockUI/ajax spinner suddenly disappears, and all of the information in the form remains, but the code seems to still process successfully in the background (i.e., requests are submitted into the back-end database).

No errors are presented in the log. This is extremely frustrating and confusing and I'm just not sure what's going on. I've tried adding the following to my commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton timeout="750000" ...
```

But to no avail. (And with other various values for timeout too but nothing worked.)

Why in the world does it just seem to stop this functionality:

```
  <p:blockUI block="classRequestForm" trigger="submit">
                            <p:graphicImage name="gfx/ajax-loader.gif" />
                        </p:blockUI>
```

After a minute? Is there any way to ensure it runs (i.e., the form is blocked with BlockUI and the Ajax loading/spinner wheel keeps displaying) until the code is done processing? I also have some addAjaxMessage() success messages that display and "PF().hide()" the form when it's done processing, but yet, like I said, after a minute the BlockUI "shade" on the form goes away, and the ajax-loader.gif spinner disappears. The form is left with the information, and the success messages are never displayed, and the user is left confused on whether it worked or not, which is unacceptable.

Any ideas on this one folks? Thanks so much.

Comment: Requests can time out. You are better of using websockets and JMS when doing work in the backend which takes a way longer time than your average request. And PrimeFaces 6 is really old. BlockUI has seen some improvements since.

Comment: Yes your HTTP Request could have timed out at 60 seconds and as also mentioned many improvements in PF since 6.1